# Как вывести данные из localStorage в input

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вывести в `<input data-max"сюда">` текущие данные ключа из localStorage

К примеру у меня есть ключ "clicks" со значением "200" мне нужно что бы данное значение появлялось в `<input data-max="здесь">`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать для это `element.dataset.max`

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.dataset.max = 99;

console.log(input);
```

```html
<input type="number">
```